# How to rotate a quote every single day

Tags: php, mysql

This isn't a programming specific question but more of a general question:

I have several quotes in my database. I can add more quotes whenever I like, but the idea is this:

Everyday a new quote is displayed and the day after that the next quote is showed. When the "limit" of the quotes is reached the first quote is displayed, allowing you to always have a quote on your website.

How would I do this?

I know there needs to be a check like "IF quote was displayed yesterday, show new quote and IF yesterdays quote is also the latest in the database start with the first quote". I absolutely have no idea how to start with this, so a little help is much appreciated!

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: put a 'this_one' field in the table, set it to 1 for id 1, run a midnight cron job to change the 'this_one' field to the next quote.

Comment: You Should move away from MySQL and use prepared statements by using apis such as mysqli or pdo

Comment: @DarylGill: does using mysqli or pdo mean moving away from MySQL?

Comment: @salman Im on Bout within PHP `mysql_*();` within your PHP code. As MySQL is not supported and is in the depreciation process to be removed from future PHP revisions. Use MySQL databases but interact with your database using MySQLI or pdo API within your code

Comment: Yes, right, but OP hasn't posted some code nor he mentioned using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Just be assumptions I thought I would mention it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function get_daily_quote(){
    $q = floor(time()/86400);  // will produce a number
    $n = 100; // num of quotes - you can count the quotes in the database or something
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `quotes` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT '.($q%$n).', 1');
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
}
```

or use pdo instead of mysql's old functions, but you get the point...

**EDIT**

just to explain - $q will always progress by 1 from the previous day. $q % $n will be the offest, when fetching the quote tuple from the table. we'll order by ID to keep the results in the same order, ID will be the auto incremented primary key. this should do the trick.

Of course if you want performance you can save it into a file and run a once a day to update it, so you will not need to query the database for it.

**EDIT**
fixed $q

Comment: +1 but FWIW we can get faster performance using `WHERE id > $q % $n`, if we can assume (or make sure) that all id values are consecutive.

Comment: great idea. shouldn't it be WHERE id = ($q % $n)+1 ? would return a single with no need for "order by" or "limit"

Comment: Yes, if you can rely on there being no gaps, then `=` would be even better than `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the quotes in the database by id e.g. 1-100 and then select it from the database at random by using the php function

```
rand(1, 100);
```

Of course you would need to save what has been chosen for that date some where maybe another table so you can check if this has been generated for the new day.

Comment: Rand is not something to use with this scenario because day 1 could equal to `rand(); = 4` this could repeat on day 3

Answer (score 0):

Galchens awnser should cover it but If you add or remove quotes you will get the same quote twice.

A better way would be to daily draw a random quote (use a cronjob)

```
SELECT * FROM Quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Add 2 fields, used and today (enum 0,1 or int 1)
set today = 1 for a random quote per day
set used = 1 if a quote has been used and todays quote

Once there are no more unused quotes left update used to 0;

Since you are already using cronjobs cache the result to a file !

Comment: but after you've finished going over all of them, you will not necessarily get the first, you loose track of the order. if so, i'd save the last id that was used and catch the next one in size, so you can remove/add without worrying

Comment: @galchen to battle this, you could create a separate table in your SQL to hold the quote rotation log, for viewing, but.also minimize the factor of repetition duplicate quotes by using said table as a reference